# MySQL multiple table join and total

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Table Animal:
id, group_id and name

Table Location:
id, group_id,animal, supplies, training, person_id,organization_id,date

Table Person
id, firstname, lastname

Table orgnization
id,  org_name
```

Details :

Animal table will have animals which  belongs to a group
Each animal in the animal may have multiple locations entried in Location table
For each animal in the location table there can be either a person_id or organization_id.

I need to get that id and look in either person or organization table for the details.

For each animal in the location table , they may have a traininig cost and supplies cost and I need to get that total

What I doing now is , Get all animals from animal table ex :

```
select * from animal where group_id=70
```

This will give me the list of animal for a group

```
select * from location where group_id=70 and animal_id = 60905442.
```

This will give a set of 5 or 6 entries and in the code I loop through each animal get a total supplies, and total training cost for each animal

```
select * from location where animal_id = ? and group_id = ? order by date
```

This is to get the latest location of the animal, as the animal might be in multiple locations.

The goal is to find the latest location of the animal .  This will have either a `person_id` or `organizagoin_id` for that animal

Then **if** there is a `person_id` for the above query , look in to `Person` table for the `first_name` and `last_name` **else** look into `organization` table for the `org_name`.

I know this can be done in one query , but need some help.

Sample table data :

```
Animal :
 id       group_id   name
 6923     A          harry
 6924     A          larry
 6925     A          Marry
 6888     B          Eddy

Location:
  id      group_id   animal_id  supplies  training person_id  org_id
  1        A         6923        10                 90          0
  2        A         6923         10         10      90          0
  3        A         6924         0          10     0           80
  4        A         6924         10        10      0           85
  5        A         6925          0        0       95          0
  6        B         6888         20       20       95          0

Person 
  id   firstname   lastname
   90   Test        Tester
   95   Sam          Tester
```

Orgnization Table
  id   organization_name
   80   Microsoft LLC
   85   Apple LLC

Desired Output :
 animal_id  group_id   name   totalsupplies  totaltraining personfirstname personlastname  orgname

Comment: "done in one query" is a strange rquirement for this data model.

Comment: I think it is possible in one query, but sample data would be very helpfull. Also in animal table you have id and animal_id, isn't this the same?

Comment: Martin, you seem new to Stackoverflow. When you ask a question then it should be just 1 questuon. But as you are new at least separate your questions to make it more understandable. You will get better response then

Comment: @Kevin the id is the person id actually. Bad naming problem here. Martin, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake. id and animal_id have both same values.  Please ignore animal_id

Comment: I tried to add sample data and expected response, but the formatting is messed up

Comment: good grief. I'm not wading through all that verbal diarrhoea. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query and start over.

Answer (score 0):

I found a query for your problem, however this is t-sql syntax. I hope this can help you further when seeing how the query is build up. I guess the row_number function is not available in MySQL.

```
declare @animal table (id int, group_id varchar(50), name varchar(50))
insert into @animal values
(6923,'A','harry'),
(6924,'A','larry'),
(6925,'A','Marry'),
(6888,'B','Eddy')

declare @location table (id int, group_id varchar(50), animal_id int, supplies int, training int, person_id int, org_id int, loc_date date)
insert into @location values
(1,'A',6923,10,null,90,0,'20170510'),
(2,'A',6923,10,10,90,0,'20170517'),
(3,'A',6924,0,10,0,80,'20170512'),
(4,'A',6924,10,10,0,85,'20170515'),
(5,'A',6925,0,0,95,0,'20170513'),
(6,'B',6888,20,20,95,0,'20170514')

declare @person table (id int, firstname varchar(50), lastname varchar(50))
insert into @person values
(90,'Test','Tester'),
(95,'Sam','Tester')

declare @organization table (id int, name varchar(50))
insert into @organization values
(80, 'Microsoft'),
(85, 'Apple')

select a.id, a.group_id, a.name, ttl.totalsupplies, ttl.totaltraining, 
    case when lastloc.person_id <> 0 then p.firstname + ' ' + p.lastname else '' end as person, 
    case when lastloc.org_id <> 0 then o.name else '' end as organization
from 
   (select m.id, m.group_id, m.animal_id, m.supplies, m.training, m.person_id, m.org_id, m.loc_date
    from 
       (select id, group_id, animal_id, supplies, training, person_id, org_id, loc_date,
            ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by animal_id order by loc_date desc) AS r
        from @location) AS m
    where m.r = 1) AS lastloc
 inner join
   (select animal_id, sum(supplies) as totalsupplies, sum(training) as totaltraining
    from @location
    group by animal_id) AS ttl
      on ttl.animal_id = lastloc.animal_id
 inner join
   @animal as a on a.id = lastloc.animal_id
 left outer join
   @person as p on p.id = lastloc.person_id
 left outer join
   @organization as o on o.id = lastloc.org_id
```

This will result in

```
id    group_id  name    totalsupplies   totaltraining   person        organization
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6923  A         harry   20              10              Test Tester 
6924  A         larry   10              20                            Apple
6925  A         Marry   0               0               Sam Tester  
6888  B         Eddy    20              20              Sam Tester
```

Comment: Thank You!.  I am going to try this.  Appreciate your time  in going through this.